# Jsoup get text in the inner div with same class name without dupplicating

Tags: android, html, text, jsoup

So I need to get the text inside this

```
<div class="posting">
    <div class="posting">
        <div class="posting">
            Sample Text
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

However, the query `select("div.posting")` returns duplicated output like

```
Sample Text
Sample Text
Sample Text
```

How can I write the query so it only returns one `Sample Text`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select("div.posting div.posting div.posting");
```

should work for you. It basically tells JSoup to give you the `div.posting` that is inside a `div.posting` which again is inside a `div.posting`.

**Edit:** If your your divs are enclosed by a `td.content` like this:

```
<td class="content">
    <div class="posting">
        <div class="posting">
            <div class="posting">
                Sample Text
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</td>
```

then this code should work, too and would be more generic:

```
select("td.content > div.posting");
```

It selects the `div.posting` that is the direct child of a `td.content`.

Comment: That one works for my specific case, but what if we don't know the number of inner `div.posting`?

Comment: Do you know the parent element of the outer `div.posting`?

Comment: Mind letting me know?

Comment: Here `document.select("table.forumpost").select("tr").select("td.content").select("div.posting")`